# window location inside if isn´t working?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I just made some stuff with my registration I send something through ajax post than do something with that data and then if (something is true) I am trying to use window.location.replace();  But it´s not working and I am driving crazy here really. Because I have it inside if, I check it with echo and every line of echo before and after that window location are done so the code does get inside that if, but that window location  like absolutly wasn´t there and it was ignored or something... problem is not with chrome or anything because when I remove that if or placed that window location somewhere else it is working, but right there in that if where I need to work, it isn´t doing anything and I am rally driving crazy here, please help :(

here si ajax code :

```
function registruj () {
    var pohlavie=[];

    $.each($("input:checked"),function(){
        pohlavie.push($(this).val());
    });
    if(pohlavie.length == 0)
        pohlavie[0] = "";
    var name =  $('#meno').val();

    var priez = $('#priezvisko').val();
    var log  = $('#login').val();
    var mail  = $('#mail').val();
    var cisloTel  = $('#cislo').val();
    var heslo = $('#heslo').val();
    var heslo1 = $('#heslo1').val();

    $.post( "registraciaudaje.php", {
            'meno': name,
            'priezvisko': priez,
            'login':log,
            'mail':mail,
            'cislo':cisloTel,
            'heslo':heslo,
            'heslo1':heslo1,
            'pohlavie':pohlavie

        }, function (data) {
            $('#result').html(data);

        }


    );
    $('#nove').load(document.URL + ' #nove');


}
```

here I use my POSTs from ajax

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST["meno"]) ) {

$_SESSION['meno'] = $_POST["meno"];
$_SESSION['priezvisko'] = $_POST["priezvisko"];
    $_SESSION['login'] = $_POST["login"];
    $_SESSION['heslo'] = $_POST["heslo"];
    $_SESSION['heslo1'] = $_POST["heslo1"];

    $_SESSION['pohlavie'] = $_POST["pohlavie"][0];

    $_SESSION['mail'] = $_POST['mail'];
    $_SESSION['cislo'] = $_POST['cislo'];
//$id = $_SESSION['id'];

}
?>
```

and my html code of page

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>blblblbl</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" media="screen" />
    <script src="jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
    <script>$(function(){$('.img').fancybox();});</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="prihlasenie.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css"> </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style1.css" />
</head>
<body class="body">
<div class="container">
    <div id="nove">
        <?php
        session_start();

        if(isset($_SESSION["meno"]) ) {

            require "pripojenie.php";
            $meno = $_SESSION["meno"];

            $priezvisko = $_SESSION["priezvisko"];
            $login = $_SESSION["login"];
            $heslo = $_SESSION["heslo"];
            $hesloZnovu = $_SESSION["heslo1"];
            if(isset($_SESSION["pohlavie"]))
                $pohlavie = $_SESSION["pohlavie"];

            $mail = $_SESSION['mail'];
            $cislo = $_SESSION['cislo'];

            unset($_SESSION['meno']);
            echo "kokot";
        }
        ?>

        <form  >
            <table style="margin-bottom:5px">
                <tr><td><label for="napdis">Vyplňte nasledujúci formulár:</label></td></tr>
                <?php  if(isset($pohlavie)) {
                    if($pohlavie == "zena") {
                        echo '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="pohlavie" value="zena" id="zena" checked>Žena</td></tr>';
                        echo '<br>';
                    }
                    else {
                        echo '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="pohlavie" value="zena" id="zena" >Žena</td></tr>';
                        echo '<br>';
                    }
                    if($pohlavie == "muz") {
                        echo '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="pohlavie" value="muz" id="muz" checked>Muž</td></tr>';
                        echo '<br>';
                    }
                    else {
                        echo '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="pohlavie" value="muz" id="muz" >Muž</td></tr>';
                        echo '<br>';
                    }

                } else {
                    echo '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="pohlavie" value="zena" id="zena" >Žena</td></tr>';
                    echo '<br>';
                    echo '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="pohlavie" value="muz" id="muz" >Muž</td></tr>';
                    echo '<br>';
                }
                ?>
                <tr><td><label for="meno">Meno :</label></td><td><input type = "text" id="meno" name="meno" value="<?php if(isset($meno)) echo $meno; ?>"></td></tr>
                <tr><td><label for="priezvisko">Priezvisko :</label></td><td><input type = "text" id="priezvisko" name="priezvisko" value="<?php if(isset($priezvisko)) echo $priezvisko; ?>"></td></tr>
                <tr><td><label for="login">Login :</label></td>
                    <td><input type = "text" id="login" name="login" value="<?php if(isset($login)) echo $login; ?>"></td></tr>

                <?php
                if(isset($heslo)) {
                    if (($heslo != "" && $hesloZnovu != "") && ($heslo == $hesloZnovu)) {
                        $chyba = 0;
                        if (strlen($heslo) < 8) {
                            $dlzka = 1;

                        }

                        if (!preg_match("#[0-9]+#", $heslo)) {

                            $cisla = 2;
                        }

                        if (!preg_match("#[a-zA-Z]+#", $heslo)) {
                            $znaky = 3;

                        }
                        if(isset($dlzka) && !isset($cisla) && !isset($znaky))
                            echo '<tr><td><label for="heslo">Heslo :</label><td><input type = "password" id="heslo"  name="heslo" value='.$hesloZnovu.'></td><td><label for="zleHeslo">Heslo musí mať aspoň 8 znakov!</label></td></tr>';
                        if(isset($cisla) && !isset($dlzka) && !isset($znaky))
                            echo '<tr><td><label for="heslo">Heslo :</label><td><input type = "password" id="heslo" name="heslo" value='.$hesloZnovu.'></td><td><label for="zleHeslo">Heslo musí obsahovať aspoň jedno číslo!</label></td></tr>';
                        if(isset($znaky)&& !isset($cisla) && !isset($dlzka))
                            echo '<tr><td><label for="heslo">Heslo :</label><td><input type = "password"  id="heslo" name="heslo" value='.$hesloZnovu.'></td><td><label for="zleHeslo">Heslo musí obsahovať aspoň jedno písmeno !</label></td></tr>';
                        if(isset($dlzka)  && isset($cisla) &&  !isset($znaky))
                            echo '<tr><td><label for="heslo">Heslo :</label><td><input type = "password" id="heslo"  name="heslo" value='.$hesloZnovu.'></td><td><label for="zleHeslo">Heslo musí mať aspoň 8 znakov a obsahovať aspoň jedno číslo !</label></td></tr>';
                        if(isset($dlzka) && isset($znaky) && !isset($cisla))
                            echo '<tr><td><label for="heslo">Heslo :</label><td><input type = "password" id="heslo" name="heslo" value='.$hesloZnovu.'></td><td><label for="zleHeslo">Heslo musí mať aspoň 8 znakov a obsahovať aspoň jeden znak !</label></td></tr>';
                        if(isset($znaky)&& isset($cisla) && !isset($dlzka) )
                            echo '<tr><td><label for="heslo">Heslo :</label><td><input type = "password" id="heslo" name="heslo" value='.$hesloZnovu.'></td><td><label for="zleHeslo">Heslo musí obsahovať aspoň jedno číslo a znak !</label></td></tr>';
                        if(isset($znaky) && isset($cisla)&& isset($dlzka))
                            echo '<tr><td><label for="heslo">Heslo :</label><td><input type = "password"  id="heslo" name="heslo" value='.$hesloZnovu.'></td><td><label for="zleHeslo">Úplne zlé heslo, musí mať aspoň 8 znakov a obsahovať aspoň jeden znak a jedno číslo !</label></td></tr>';
                        if(!isset($znaky) && !isset($cisla)&& !isset($dlzka)){
                            $hesloOk = 1;
                        }
                    }
                    else {

                        echo '<tr><td><label for="heslo">Heslo :</label><td><input type = "password" id="heslo" name="heslo" value='.$hesloZnovu.'></td><td><label for="zleHeslo">Heslá sa nezhodujú</label></td></tr>';
                        $pocet = 1;
                    }
                }

                ?>
                <?php

                if(!isset($pocet) && !isset($heslo) ) {

                    echo'<tr ><td ><label for="heslo" > Heslo :</label ></td >
                <td ><input type = "password"  id="heslo" name = "heslo" ></td ></tr >';

                }
                if(!isset($pocet) && isset($heslo) && !isset($znaky) && !isset($cisla)&& !isset($dlzka)) {

                    echo'<tr ><td ><label for="heslo" > Heslo :</label ></td >
                <td ><input type = "password"  id="heslo" name = "heslo" value='.$heslo.'></td ></tr >';

                }
                ?>
                <tr><td><label for="heslo2">Heslo znovu :</label></td>
                    <td><input type = "password"  id="heslo1" name="heslo1" value="<?php if(isset($hesloZnovu)) echo $hesloZnovu; ?>" ></td></tr>
                <?php
                if(isset($mail)) {
                    if (!stristr($mail, "@") OR !stristr($mail, ".")) {
                        echo '<tr><td><label for="email">E-mail :</label></td>
                    <td><input type = "text" id="mail" name="email" value='.$mail.'></td><td><label for="zlyMail">Zlý formát emailu</label></td></rd></tr>';
                    } else {
                        $mailOk = 1;
                        echo '<tr><td><label for="email">E-mail :</label></td>
                    <td><input type = "text" id="mail"  name="email" value='.$mail.'></td><td></tr>';
                    }
                }
                else {  ?>
                    <tr><td><label for="email">E-mail :</label></td>
                        <td><input type = "text" id="mail" name="email" value="<?php if(isset($mail)) echo $mail; ?>" > </td></tr>

                <?php } ?>


                <?php  if(isset($cislo) || isset($cisloOk))   {
                    //$pattern = '~^(\+420)? ?\d{3} ?\d{3} ?\d{3}$~';
                    //$phoneNumber = '+420 123 456 789';
                    // $predvolby = array('737', '777', '603', '606');
                    //$predvolbyStr = implode('|', $predvolby);
                    $pattern = '~^(\+421)? ?\d{3} ?\d{3} ?\d{3}$~';
                    if (preg_match($pattern, $cislo))
                        $cisloOk =1;
                    else
                        echo '<tr><td><label for="cislo">Telefónne číslo :</label></td>
                <td><input type = "text" id="cislo" name="cislo" value="'.$cislo .'"></td><td><label for="zleCislo">Zlý formát čísla (Príklad : +421 111 222 333) </label></td></tr>';
                }
                ?>
                <?php if(!isset($cislo) || isset($cisloOk)){ ?>
                    <tr><td><label for="cislo">Telefónne číslo :</label></td>
                        <td><input type = "text" id="cislo" name="cislo" value="<?php if(isset($cislo)) echo $cislo; ?>" ></td></tr>
                <?php } ?>
                <tr><td><input type="button" value="Zaregistrovať" onclick="registruj()" ></td></tr>
            </table>
        </form>

        <?php
        if(isset($mailOk) && isset($hesloOk) && isset($cisloOk)) {
            require "pripojenie.php";
            $length = 20;

            $randomString = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, $length);    
            $zasifrovane = crypt($heslo,$randomString);

            mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO uzivatelia (Meno,Priezvisko,Login,Heslo,mail,pohlavie,cislo) VALUES ('$meno','$priezvisko','$login','$zasifrovane','$mail','$pohlavie','$cislo')");

            echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location.replace("index.php"); </script>';

        }
        ?>

    </div>
<div id="result"></div>

</div>
</body>
```

and that window location almost on the end of the html code isn´t working.. Why ? On every place outside of if is working but inside if it isn´t working... But the everything inside that if is being done so that window location is like ignored or something, do you have any ideas please ?

Comment: did you check if the `if()` block that win.loc call is in is actually triggering? plus, your db code is vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: I checked it I wrote it in description of my question that the if is 100% triggering that´s why I absolutly don´t understand it... if I write echo "here"; then window.location.replace("index.php"); and then echo "there";  both echo shows on page and window location is like ignored or I don´t know

Comment: is it possible to redirect the page directly on the server side?

Comment: do you have any error in browser console?

Comment: no nothing.. everything is clear whole time... I absolutly don´t know what´s going on

Comment: Check the generated HTML source code. [Validate](https://validator.w3.org/) it. Check the browser console.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly after the ajax post you do not submit the page so the same page continue to have no window.replace because the first time you have not checked the login.

The flow should be:

. your PHP generate the page

. the first time the page does not contain the window.replace

. after checked something with your ajax post call you can submit the form:

```
$('form').trigger('submit');
```

Try to change your file registraciaudaje.php so that you set a new variable session like:

```
$_SESSION['postOk'] = 'ok';
```

in the page where you have:

```
if(isset($mailOk) && isset($hesloOk) && isset($cisloOk)) {
```

you can do a check like

```
$postOk = $_SESSION["postOk"];
if (isset($postOk)) {
header('location: index.php');
exit();
}
```

Comment: What's the point of putting something in `$("#result").html()` if you're redirecting to `index.php`?

Comment: but the problem is that I need to make that location.replace only if email, password and phone number are in valid form and the registration has benn successfull... and that´s why I have it in that if... but registration is done okay, it´s write in database everything inside that if is being done but that window location is not...

Comment: so what should I do ? according your eddited answer ? I still don´t know what to do

Comment: yea I already noticed that the window replace is not there... but what you mean by posting the whole page ? I may sound like an idiot already but please can you tell me what I should do ?

Comment: yes but when I add it in my ajax post then the location replace is being done before the other stuff that I needed are done, so this is not the solution... and when I set the location.reload on page somewhere then the page is like still being reloading over and over and over and I can´t  do anything :D and when I give it inside and if then it´s not beingy reload at all because it´s like before isn´t reloaded yet... so I am giving up slowly... thanks for you time and help bytheway :)

Comment: yea now it´s working, but the whole point of doing this thing throguh AJAX was that if I set an incorrect data then my page will show me it without refreshing the page, and If aj set the correct data then in will register me an redirect to my login, now it´s working but it´s doing page reload... :( I don´t know how I should do it

Comment: so in my php where I send those post I should set another session variable and what I should do with that ? this part I don´t understand..

Comment: so I add an session in the php : registraciaudaje, where ajax was sent and then I am checking if that session is set in my registracion document an if it is I wrote header("Location:index.php"); but here the header location doesn´t working...

Comment: yes I am trying something like that but header location locate me to the page with white space ( empty page )

Comment: try to add exit(); after header('location: index.php');